# Replacing string with regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to extract from a string like this:

```
$message = #porrabarça per avui @RTorq el  @FCBar guanyarà per 3-1 al AC Milan
```

The '3-1'. As Number - Number

I've tried

```
$message = preg_replace('/[0-9]\s*-\s[0-9]/i', '', $message);
```

But it isnt working. It's output is the same as the input.

Can you help me out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is `\s` here.

```
/[0-9]\s*-\s[0-9]/
           ^
           |
           +--- This makes a single space mandatory.
```

You need `\s*` there. Use [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) to extract anything. `preg_match` matches and optionally set the match to a variable. From there you can extract the matches. [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) replaces the matched content.

```
preg_match("/\d+\s*-\s*\d+/", $message, $match);
$num = $match[0];
```

http://ideone.com/BWKZQV

To replace use this pattern and empty string as replace string in `preg_replace`.

A better pattern would using POSIX character classes. it'll match any type digit characters of any other locale.

```
/[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]*-[[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]+/
```

Comment: Capturing group is not needed here. It only matches what is needed.

Comment: Thank you. This is working like charm. As input can also cointain results like ´number_space_'-'_space_number´ I've removed all spaces from every input.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace the string :

```
<?php  
$message="#porrabarça per avui @RTorq el  @FCBar guanyarà per 3-1 al AC Milan";

echo $message = preg_replace('/[0-9]+-[0-9]+/', '', $message);

?>
```

If you want to get matched groups :

```
<?php  
$message="#porrabarça per avui @RTorq el  @FCBar guanyarà per 3-1 al AC Milan";

preg_match_all('/[0-9]+-[0-9]+/', $message, $matches);

print_r($matches);

?>
```

Comment: `/i` is not needed here. Digits has no case-sensivity